# Saving a UIImage from a UIView not working properly

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, core-graphics

I'm attempting to save the contents of a UIView (and it's subviews) into a UIImage.

Here is the code I am using:

```
+(UIImage *)imageWithView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions([view bounds].size, YES, 0);
    [[view layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

It works great... the first time.  However, if I then modify subviews of the view and call this method again, I get the old UIImage *every* time.

It's my understanding that `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` does in fact pop the bitmap image off of the stack.

How can I make this imageWithView: method work, taking into account the current state of the view's subviews?

Comment: dude I wasn't able to reproduce the issue you mentioned. I tried it with your code and it worked perfectly after changing sub-views of a view. See this screenshot http://cl.ly/image/0W1A1k3p121Q . Plz make sure that you're not holding a previous reference in your variables of the old image.

Answer (score -2):

I hope this helps:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[testView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```